# How to mask a column in Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, data-masking

I've a requirement to keep a user table for granting access to an application where there's a password field which has to be masked.

How to go about it?

Example: If you query `select * from PG_USER;` in Redshift, you'd see, the password column values are shown as `*****`. How to do exactly that for my custom table?

Comment: Store it in a different table or encrypt it in the column.  Don't store clear-text passwords anywhere.  And put them only in places where users don't have access.

Comment: How to encrypt it at a column level?

Comment: You don't encrypt password in table directly. This should be handled by script which inserts data into table. And when authentication is done, you compare encrypted data from table against encrypted provided password. If encryption algorithm (or most probably hash of password) is the same, then there will be a match.

Comment: @GordonLinoff What do you mean by "store it in different table"? Do you mean create a view which doesn't show the password column when listing users and their other details?

Comment: @EdgarsT. I was thinking of doing exactly the same, but kept it in second position of my priority list, first being a simple masking. So at the same time, I had this query in mind, i.e, how does Redshift do it for the table I mentioned in the question, how do they mask it when select * is done? I wasn't allowed to see its SQL Source which would have helped me in figuring out the masking logic. Any help on that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is a column in a table that you do not wish particular users to see, then:

- Do not grant them permission to use the table
- Use `CREATE VIEW` to select all columns you *do* wish them to be able to view
- Grant them permission to use the view
- Tell them to use the view instead of the table (they operate identically)

Or, create a table without the offending column and grant them permission to use that table.

Comment: I'll do so. But at the same time, I had this query in mind, i.e, how does Redshift do it for the table I mentioned in the question, how do they mask it when select * is done? I wasn't allowed to see its SQL Source which would have helped me in figuring out the masking logic. Any help on that?

Comment: The `PG_USER` table is a special system table. Listing passwords would violate security, so the masking is probably in-built into PostgreSQL (upon which Redshift was built).

Comment: The idea to use VIEWs is a possible solution for you. I want to suggest to use some external solution like DataSunrise which could help you to use reach your target for masking data for some users.

Answer (score 0):

with redshift supporting dynamic masking..  create a mask rule (this one I replace all characters with X, except the first, last and any '@' :

`CREATE MASKING POLICY name_mask WITH (name_col VARCHAR(2000)) USING (left(name_col,1) || REGEXP_REPLACE(substring(name_col,2,abs(len(name_col)-2)), '[^ @]', 'X') || right(name_col,1)::TEXT);`

Then simply attach that masking to the column:

`ATTACH MASKING POLICY name_mask ON custom_table(name_column) TO PUBLIC;`

This will reflect in all user's queries now.
You can use different roles, etc, rather than PUBLIC if you want to start dividing up your security levels.

Obviously if you are doing this for a password field, you can alter the above to mask it all.

Answer (score -1):

Following post shows how to implment encryption UDF in Redshift with some data protection best practices.
 https://techsboot.com/blogs/redshift/encrypt_decrypt_udf_using_pyaes/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25573058)